# Coordinate timing on CSS animations

Tags: css, css-animations

I've looked around trying to find exactly what it is Im trying to explain on here to see if someone has asked the same question, however I'm not sure my wording is correct.

What I have is three animations that I'm trying to coordinate timing on. I have transitioning background, a fade in title and an animated shape. I'm trying to get them to run in a sequence and I'm not sure how to go about doing that. I dont have code on hand so just examples would be amazing. To give you an idea of what I'm looking for circlek.com's title/banner is basically it.

Comment: JavaScript funtction: setTimeout(function, milliseconds).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below an example of 3 sequential animations.

`animation: fadeInText 1s 2s ease-in forwards;` means there is a 2 seconds delay before the animation starts and it takes 1 second to complete it.

Hope this helps. More details [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp)

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}

.anim1 {
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  animation: backGroundColor 1s 1s ease-in forwards;
}

.anim2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 100px;
  font-size: 3rem;
  color: white;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: fadeInText 1s 2s ease-in forwards;
}

.anim3 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  animation: rotateSquare 1s 4s ease-in forwards;
}

@keyframes backGroundColor {
  0% {
    background-color: white;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: blue;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeInText {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes rotateSquare {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    background-color: white;
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="anim1"></div>
  <div class="anim2">Lorem Ipsum</div>
  <div class="anim3"></div>
</div>
```